# Inner Panel doesnt respond

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

So my goal is do create a settings Window. On the left side you have the different categories. Which you can switch by clicking on them. On the right side is the panel that will switch the content based on what thing you clicked on.

I implemented it by creating a class for every content panel, instantiate it from the frame and Hide all the panels except the one that was choosen.

My problem is that i cant interact with anything inside the panels that i hide and show. Here is a minimum example that you should be able to run.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 13 15:54:51 2021

@author: Odatas
"""

import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

#First Panel
class settingsConnection(wx.ScrolledWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent,size):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self,parent=parent,size=size)
        self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)
        self.infoText = wx.StaticText(self
                                      ,label="I'm Panel settingsConnection\n\nUnder construction."
                                      ,style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL)
        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.infoText)

#Second Panel
class settingsGeneral(wx.ScrolledWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent,size):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self,parent=parent,size=size)
        self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)
        self.infoText = wx.StaticText(self
                                      ,label="I'm  Panel settingsGeneral\n\nUnder construction."
                                      ,style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL)
        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.infoText)

#Third Panel
class settingsABC(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):

    def __init__(self,parent,size):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self,parent=parent,size=size)
        self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)

        self.firstSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.secondSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.thridSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)

        self.autoStartCheckBox=wx.CheckBox(self, label="Button")
        self.autoStartCheckBox.SetValue(True)

        self.testButton = wx.Button(self,label="Test")

        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.autoStartCheckBox)
        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.testButton)

        self.topLevelSizer.Layout()
        self.Fit()

#The main frame that holds all the panels
class settingsWindow(wx.Frame):

    FLAG_KILL_ME = False


    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent.frame,size=(1000,800),style= wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX |wx.STAY_ON_TOP|wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)
        
        #Event for Closing window
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.onQuit)
        #Event for changing the focus
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_FOCUSED,self.onFocusChange)
        self.parent=parent
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panelSize=(800,700)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
        #Contains Everything Level 0
        self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #Contains Top Part Level 01
        self.windowSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #Contains Bottom part Level 01
        self.buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #Contains Widgets for Mainpart
        self.widgetSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)
        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.windowSizer)
        self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.buttonSizer)
        
        self.settingsChooser=wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY,style=wx.LC_LIST|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL,size=(100,700))
        self.settingsChooser.AppendColumn("Test")

        self.windowSizer.Add(self.settingsChooser)
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.widgetSizer)

        self.panelList=[]
        self.settingsChooser.InsertItem(0,"Allgemein")
        self.generalPanel=settingsGeneral(self,self.panelSize)
        self.panelList.append(self.generalPanel)
        self.widgetSizer.Add(self.generalPanel)


        self.settingsChooser.InsertItem(1,"Connection")
        self.connectionPanel=settingsConnection(self,self.panelSize)
        self.panelList.append(self.connectionPanel)
        self.widgetSizer.Add(self.connectionPanel)
        self.connectionPanel.Hide()

        self.settingsChooser.InsertItem(2,"DLT")
        self.dltPanel=settingsABC(self,self.panelSize)
        self.panelList.append(self.dltPanel)
        self.widgetSizer.Add(self.dltPanel)
        self.dltPanel.Hide()

        self.currentID=0
        self.panel.Fit()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        #self.mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.downloadEndPackageMethod)
        #self.mythread.start()
        while self.FLAG_KILL_ME is False:
            wx.GetApp().Yield()


        try:
            self.Destroy()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        
    #Shows the Selected Panel and hides the current shown.
    def onFocusChange(self,event=None):
        self.panelList[self.currentID].Hide()
        self.panelList[event.GetIndex()].Show()
        self.currentID=event.GetIndex()
        self.panel.Fit()
        self.panel.Layout()


    def onQuit(self,event=None):
        self.FLAG_KILL_ME = True
        self.Hide()
#Main wx.Python App        
class Testapp(wx.App): 
    
    def __init__(self,redirect=False,filename=None):


        wx.App.__init__(self,redirect,filename)
        self.frame=wx.Frame(None,title="Test")
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self.frame,size=(1000,1000))
        self.TopLevelSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.TopLevelSizer)
        self.settingsButton = wx.Button(self.panel,label="Settings")
        self.TopLevelSizer.Add(self.settingsButton)
        self.settingsButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openSettings)        
        self.frame.Show()
        
    def openSettings(self,event=None):
        settingsWindow(self)
           
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=Testapp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Edit: Adjustest class "Settings Window" für use with wx.Listbook

```
class settingsWindow(wx.Frame):

FLAG_KILL_ME = False


def __init__(self,parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent.frame,size=(1000,800),style= wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX |wx.STAY_ON_TOP|wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.onQuit)
    # self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_FOCUSED,self.onFocusChange)
    self.parent=parent
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.panelSize=(800,700)
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
    #Contains Everything Level 0
    self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    #Contains Top Part Level 01
    self.windowSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #Contains Bottom part Level 01
    self.buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #Contains Widgets for Mainpart
    self.widgetSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.panel.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)
    self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.windowSizer)
    self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.buttonSizer)
    self.windowSizer.Add(self.widgetSizer)

    self.settingsBook = wx.Listbook(self.panel)
    self.widgetSizer.Add(self.settingsBook)

    self.settingsBook.InsertPage(0, settingsGeneral(self,self.panelSize), "Settins")
    self.settingsBook.InsertPage(1, settingsConnection(self,self.panelSize), "Connections")
    self.settingsBook.InsertPage(2, settingsABC(self,self.panelSize), "ABC")
    self.panel.Fit()






    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

    while self.FLAG_KILL_ME is False:
        wx.GetApp().Yield()


    try:
        self.Destroy()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def onQuit(self,event=None):
    self.FLAG_KILL_ME = True
    self.Hide()
```

Comment: There's an existing class to do this for you called [wx.Simplebook](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Simplebook.html).

Comment: Damn. Nice to know. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Or `wx.Listbook` is simplicity itself, with a `tab` for each group of settings.

Comment: I tried it with wx.Listbook since wx.Simplebook is as far as i think the same only that it cant be user controlled and i would have to write my own change class like i did allready. 

But the problem persists. When showing the pannels Checkboxes and Buttons are not usable. I edit my post to include the new class where i used wx.Listbook, so you can check for yourself.

Comment: What is the purpose of `while self.FLAG_KILL_ME is False:`? You can't expect things to work if you just call `Yield()` in a loop, you have to enter the event loop normally.

Comment: The self.FLAG_KILL_ME has the purpos to Destroy the Window when the user close it. The Settingswindow im trying to implement is the second window. There is another Window which is the main Window of the Program. When i open the new Window the GUI Loop will be inside that Window. Once it leaves the window it will close down. So i have to keep the loop inside and to have the main window still respond to Stuff i need to Yield to the App.

Comment: The mainloop remains the same, it does not swap about with each window that opens.

Comment: Yes. But when you open a new frame the mainloop stays in that frame. Nothing outside the frame would get updated. When you exit the frame it would just close. So i yield to the App from inside the second frame. 

How else would you implement multi window?

Comment: @Odatas I've amended my example code, in an attempt to persuade you, concerning the `MainLoop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a standalone `Listbook` example taken from a working project.
I've hacked out the meat and left the potatoes. :)

Edit:

I have added a simple main frame from where you activate the configuration code. The `main` frame contains a counter, in an attempt to convince you, that the `MainLoop` is still active, as you seem to believe it gets hijacked in some way.

Hopefully, it will be of use.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
#from os.path import expanduser

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Main Window", size=(300, 200))
        self.cnt = 0
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Open Config", pos=(10, 10), size=(120, 30))
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Is the main loop still active", pos=(10, 50))
        self.counter = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", pos=(10, 80), size=(120, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnConfig, button)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.Show()
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    def OnConfig(self, event):
        frame = Config(parent=self)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.counter.SetValue(str(self.cnt))

class Config(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, wx.ID_ANY,"Configuration",size=(600,400))

        #self.home_dir = expanduser("~")
        #self.conf_dir = expanduser("~/fs2")
        #self.config_file = self.conf_dir+"/fs2.cfg"
        self.parent = parent
        # Create the first tab and add it to the listbook
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.lb = wx.Listbook(self.panel)

        self.tab1 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.lb, -1)
        self.tab1.SetupScrolling()
        self.tab1.SetBackgroundColour("Grey")
        self.lb.AddPage(self.tab1, "Foot Pedal")


        t1_1 = wx.StaticText(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Pedal Device"))
        self.fc_hidfile = wx.TextCtrl(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, "",size=(150, -1))
        t1_2 = wx.StaticText(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Pedal 1 *"))
        self.fc_pedal_1 = wx.ComboBox(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("Jump Back"), ("Play/Pause"), ("Jump Forward"),("Timestamp"),("Unclear"),("Comment Time stamp"),("Bookmark Time stamp"),("OSD Time stamp"),("Pedal De-activated")],style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        t1_3 = wx.StaticText(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Pedal 2 *"))
        self.fc_pedal_2 = wx.ComboBox(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("Jump Back"), ("Play/Pause"), ("Jump Forward"),("Timestamp"),("Unclear"),("Comment Time stamp"),("Bookmark Time stamp"),("OSD Time stamp"),("Pedal De-activated")],style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        t1_4 = wx.StaticText(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Pedal 3 *"))
        self.fc_pedal_3 = wx.ComboBox(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("Jump Back"), ("Play/Pause"), ("Jump Forward"),("Timestamp"),("Unclear"),("Comment Time stamp"),("Bookmark Time stamp"),("OSD Time stamp"),("Pedal De-activated")],style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        t1_5 = wx.StaticText(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Classic"))
        self.fc_classic = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab1, wx.ID_ANY,"0", min=0, max=2)#, ("Classic Play/Pause"))
        t1sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(10,2,5,5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(self.fc_hidfile, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(self.fc_pedal_1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(self.fc_pedal_2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_4, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(self.fc_pedal_3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_5, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(self.fc_classic, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


        self.tab1.SetSizer(t1sizer)

        self.tab2 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.lb, -1)
        self.tab2.SetupScrolling()
        self.tab2.SetBackgroundColour("Grey")
        self.lb.AddPage(self.tab2, "Control")

        t2_1 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Include Hours in Time display"))
        self.fc_time_disp = wx.ComboBox(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("H"),("M")],style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        t2_2 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Jump Length (secs) *"))
        self.fc_jump_length = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, "3", min=1, max=15)
        t2_3 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Long Jump *"))
        self.fc_l_jump_length = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY,value="", min=0, max=60)
        t2_4 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Extra Long Jump *"))
        self.fc_xl_jump_length = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY,value="", min=0, max=600)
        t2_5 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Pause Jump (secs) *"))
        self.fc_pause_jump = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, "0", min=0, max=5)
        t2_6 = wx.StaticText(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Instant Loop length *"))
        self.fc_ill = wx.SpinCtrl(self.tab2, wx.ID_ANY, "10", min=3, max=20)

        t2sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(10,2,5,5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_time_disp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_jump_length, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_l_jump_length, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_4, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_xl_jump_length, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_5, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_pause_jump, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_6, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(self.fc_ill, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.tab2.SetSizer(t2sizer)

        # Create and add more tabs....

#        read the config file and load in the data

#        cfg = ConfigObj(infile = self.config_file)
#        try:
#            r_hidfile = cfg["control"]["HID_FILE_ID"]
#        except:
#            r_hid_file = "/dev/input/eventx"
#        self.fc_hidfile.SetValue(r_hid_file)
# 
# For demo purposes set fixed values

        self.fc_hidfile.SetValue('/dev/input/eventx')
        self.fc_time_disp.SetStringSelection('H')
        self.fc_jump_length.SetValue(2)
        self.fc_l_jump_length.SetValue(10)
        self.fc_xl_jump_length.SetValue(15)
        self.fc_pause_jump.SetValue(1)
        self.fc_classic.SetValue(0)
        self.fc_pedal_1.SetSelection(0)
        self.fc_pedal_2.SetSelection(1)
        self.fc_pedal_3.SetSelection(2)
        self.fc_ill.SetValue(5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.lb, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.fc_Save = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Save")
        self.fc_Quit = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Quit")
        self.help_button = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Help")
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(self.fc_Save)
        button_sizer.Add(self.fc_Quit)
        button_sizer.Add(self.help_button)
        sizer.Add(button_sizer)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.fc_Save.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave)
        self.fc_Quit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.help_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnHelp)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
        self.Close()

    def OnHelp(self, event):
        #  ShowHelp(parent=None,section='fs2_Config1.pdf')
        return

    def OnSave(self,event):
        #cfg = ConfigObj(infile = self.config_file, create_empty=True, write_empty_values=True, list_values=False)
        # write back new configuartion values here
        #cfg["control"]["FOOTPEDAL_VPID_LOCK"] = footpedal_vpid_lock
        #cfg.write()
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Test(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

You'll notice, that despite the `Config` window being active, the `Main` windows counter is `still` active.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked. For some reasone creating the panels as classes doesnt. I think i would need to start a new thread for each panel. But i wont test it. Your solution works for me. Thanks